# How to manually commit kafka offset after FileIO in apache beam?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

I have a `FileIO` writing a `Pcollection<GenericRecord>` to files and returns `WriteFilesResult<DestinationT>`.

I would like to create a `DoFn` after writing files to commit the offset of written records to kafka but since my offsets are stored in my GenericRecords I can no longer access them in the output of `FileIO`.

What is the best way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is how I did:

- manually groupbykey records by `DestinationT`
- for each group I get the list of offsets and I create a new key `EnrichedDestinationT` + flatten the iterable
- so the Pcollection before entering FileIO is `PCollection<KV<EnrichedDestinationT, GenericRecord>>`
- in FileIO, the .by() becomes `.by(KV::getKey)` and the .via() becomes `.via(Contextful.fn(KV::getValue), Contextful.fn(this::getSink))`

Comment: very interesting! thanks for sharing : ) this is a good use case

Comment: @Jean Wisser : can you share the example code ?